# How to dynamically bind a WinJS list view within a repeater

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I have a WinJS Repeater which is using a template. That template contains a WinJS list view. I can't seem to figure out how to use *data-win-bind* to set the inner list views *itemDataSource*.

My Repeater:

```
<section id="genreView" aria-label="Main content" role="main">
    <div id="genreWrapper">
        <div id="genreRows" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater"
             data-win-options="{template: select('#genreRowTemplate')}">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

My Template which contains a List View:

```
<div id="genreRowTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div id="genreRow">
        <h2 class="genreTitle" data-win-bind="innerText: genreTitle"></h2>
        <div class="genreMovieListView"
                data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
                data-win-bind="itemDataSource : data"
                data-win-options="{ layout: { type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout },
            itemsDraggable: false,
            selectionMode: 'single',
            tapBehavior: 'none',
            swipeBehavior: 'none',
            itemsReorderable: false,
            itemTemplate: select('#genreMovieTemplate')}">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My List View's template:

```
<div id="genreMovieTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="genreMovieItem">
        <img style="width: 175px; height: 250px;" data-win-bind="alt: title; src: posterUrl" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The data for the repeater is similar to this (only it's a binding list):

```
var repeaterData = [{genreTitle: "titleA", data: new WinJS.Binding.List() },
{genreTitle: "titleB", data: new WinJS.Binding.List() }
{genreTitle: "titleC", data: new WinJS.Binding.List() }
{genreTitle: "titleD", data: new WinJS.Binding.List() }];
```

The data is created on the fly and each binding list is actually a lot more data so I can't get a good sample of real data.

What I DO get is a repeated control, repeated exactly the number of times as the records in my bound list. What I DON'T get is the binding list displayed. My inner binding list is not getting databound via the data-win-bind. I've tried a few things and I either get nothing or an error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I *think* the right way to bind would be data-win-bind="data-win-options.itemDataSource: data", but doing that throws the following confusing error: "JavaScript runtime error: WinJS.UI.Repeater.AsynchronousRender: Top level items must render synchronously".

Comment: Just an idea, have tried data-win-bind="{winControl.itemDataSource: data}"?

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion. I thought of that after posting and tried it... no luck though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem, but I don't think I went about it in the right way. I went ahead and set the data source for the repeater, which gives me my genreRows from above. This was always working, it was just the child dataSource I couldn't figure out how to get to. My solution... set it in code after it loads. Nothing fancy, just a solution that feels a bit hacky to me. Here's my code in case it helps someone else get past this problem.

> ```
>  var titleList = $(".genreRow > .genreTitle");
>     var genreLists = $(".genreRow > .genreMovieListView");
>     for (var i = 0; i < genreLists.length; i++) {
>         var title = titleList[i].innerText;
>         var listControl = genreLists[i].winControl;
>
>         tempData.forEach(function (element, i) {
>             if (element.genreTitle == title)
>                 listControl.itemDataSource = element.data.dataSource;
>         });
>     };
> ```

Basically the above code assumes the title is unique (which it is). So it uses this as a key to traverse the data and set the itemDataSource that way.

I won't mark this as the accepted answer just in case someone can point out how to do this "right".

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but still deserves a good answer:

I've modified your HTML to show the correct binding syntax.

```
<div id="genreRowTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
<div id="genreRow">
    <h2 class="genreTitle" data-win-bind="innerText: genreTitle"></h2>
    <div class="genreMovieListView"
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
            data-win-bind="winControl.itemDataSource : data.dataSource"
            data-win-options="{ layout: { type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout },
        itemsDraggable: false,
        selectionMode: 'single',
        tapBehavior: 'none',
        swipeBehavior: 'none',
        itemsReorderable: false,
        itemTemplate: select('#genreMovieTemplate')}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the `winControl.itemDataSource` and `data.dataSource`.  Any WinJS control property that is not a standard HTML element property needs the `winControl` property in front of whatever property you are databinding.  So the `onclick` property of a `button` element doesn't need it, but `WinJS.UI.Command` has `icon` which is not on the underlying `button` so needs the `winControl` prefix.

Also, ListView controls bind to a WinJS.Binding.List's `dataSource` property, not the List itself.  For some reason, a repeater binds to the ListView itself however.